# Append Dictionary values to existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, append

I have an empty dataframe with 30 col, I am parsing each file and extracting the data extracting the metadata into a dictionary, the keys of dictionary match the col headers of dataframe, the number of keys in the dictionary depends on whats available in the file, how to insert a row into the dataframe based on values in dictionary?

**Data in File:**

```
 Col1                 Col2    Col3
 PD  .                 DD:   PERMANENT DATUM
 LMF .                 RT:   LOG MEASURED FROM
 DAPD.FT               98:   FEET ABOVE PERMANENT DATUM
 DMF .                 RT:   DRILLING MEASURED FROM
 EKB .FT               100:   KELLY BUSHING
 EGL .FT             -500:   GROUND LEVEL
 DATE.           08/12/95:   RUN DATE
 RUN .                  3:   RUN NUMBER}
```

**Dataframe headers** : PERMANENT DATUM, LOG MEASURED FROM, FEET ABOVE PERMANENT DATUM,DRILLING MEASURED FROM,KELLY BUSHING

**Desired output :**
 The values in Col2 column should be converted as a row and match the Col33 value to dataframe header and insert a row

I wrote a code to parse the file and convert to dictionary :

`{'PERMANENT DATUM': 'DD', 'LOG MEASURED FROM': 'RT', 'FEET ABOVE PERMANENT DATUM': '98', 'DRILLING MEASURED FROM': 'RT', 'KELLY BUSHING': '100', 'GROUND LEVEL': '500', 'RUN DATE': '08/12/95', 'RUN NUMBER': '3'}`

How to append the values in this dictionary to existing data frame? the keys in the dictionary matches dataframe headrs and is always a subset of dataframe headers.

Comment: Why bother with the empty DataFrame? Use a dict of dicts `{'file_name': dict_for_file}` to store each file, then you can construct it all at once with `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` probably using `orient='index'`. `reindex` if you then want a certain order or fields that never appeared in any file.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your problem correctly, given the following inputs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['PERMANENT DATUM', 'LOG MEASURED FROM', 'FEET ABOVE PERMANENT DATUM', 'DRILLING MEASURED FROM', 'KELLY BUSHING', 'GROUND LEVEL', 'RUN DATE', 'RUN NUMBER'])

row = {'PERMANENT DATUM': 'DD', 'LOG MEASURED FROM': 'RT', 'FEET ABOVE PERMANENT DATUM': '98', 'DRILLING MEASURED FROM': 'RT', 'KELLY BUSHING': '100', 'GROUND LEVEL': '500', 'RUN DATE': '08/12/95', 'RUN NUMBER': '3'}
```

you want to add a line to the dataframe, and you just do it like this:

```
df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```

and gives:

```
  PERMANENT DATUM LOG MEASURED FROM FEET ABOVE PERMANENT DATUM  \
0              DD                RT                         98   

  DRILLING MEASURED FROM KELLY BUSHING GROUND LEVEL  RUN DATE RUN NUMBER  
0                     RT           100          500  08/12/95          3
```